# Populating a new data frame with summaries from a large dataset of counts and years

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to teach myself about manipulating and summarizing large datasets. I’d like to create a new data frame and populate it with summary data about the years associated with count observations by location. I've created an example data frame below.

```
example.frame <- data.frame(
                   "Obs.ID" = 1:50, 
                   "Species" = rep("T. rex", 50),
                   "Site" = c(rep("Big Red", 24), rep("Supermax", 26)),
                   "Site.ID" = c(rep("1578", 24), rep("0185", 26)),
                   "Year" = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2002,
                              2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004,
                              2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005, 
                              2006, 2006, 2007, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978,
                              1979, 1979, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000,
                              2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003,
                              2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2006,
                              2006),
                   "Count" = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0,
                               0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 8, 11, 7,
                               2, 3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0,
                               0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'd like to create a new data frame summarizing these example data and include the following columns, defined below.

**Line.ID** – A unique sequential identifier for the line in the data frame starting with 1
**Site** – The site name from example.data
**Total.years** – The total number of unique years associated with the site
**Years.3** – The number of years with at least three associated counts for the site, including zeros
**Years.4** – The number of years with at least four associated counts for the site, including zeros
**Years.5** – The number of years with at least five or more associated counts for the site, including zeros
**Total.pos** – The total number of years with at least one count for the site above zero
**Pos.3** – The number of years with at least three counts for the site above zero
**Pos.4** – The number of years with at least four counts for the site above zero
**Pos.5** – The number of years with at least five counts for the site above zero

The new data frame should look like this:

```
new.frame <- data.frame(
               "Line.ID" = c(1, 2),
               "Site" = c("Big Red", "Supermax"),
               "Total.years" = c(9, 10),
               "Years.3" = c(4, 5),
               "Years.4" = c(2, 3),
               "Years.5" = c(2, 1),
               "Total.pos" = c(8, 8),
               "Pos.3" = c(3, 5),
               "Pos.4" = c(1, 2),
               "Pos.5" = c(1, 0),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I think the right way to go about it would be some combination of 'summarise' and 'group_by' in dplyr, but I can't figure out how to put it all together. I wasn't able to find an answered question that would work for this scenario, so I thought this would be useful to post.

Follow up question:
How would I incorporate an additional layer into creating the summary table (for example, adding an additional species that occurs at the same sites)? Example data frame below.

```
example.frame.2 <- data.frame(
                     "Obs.ID" = 1:80,
                     "Species" = c(rep("T. rex", 50),
                                   rep("T. bataar", 30)),
                     "Site" = c(rep("Big Red", 24),
                                rep("Supermax", 26),
                                rep("Big Red", 16),
                                rep("Supermax", 10),
                                rep("Oz", 4)),
                     "Site.ID" = c(rep("1578", 24), rep("0185", 26),
                                   rep("1578", 16), rep("0185", 10),
                                   rep("2115", 4)),
                     "Year" = c(1999, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2002,
                                2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004,
                                2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005,
                                2006, 2006, 2007, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978,
                                1979, 1979, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2000,
                                2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2003,
                                2003, 2003, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2006,
                                2006, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004,
                                2004, 2004, 2004, 2004, 2005, 2005, 2005,
                                2006, 2006, 2007, 1978, 1978, 1978, 1978,
                                1979, 1979, 1999, 1999, 2000, 2000, 2012,
                                2012, 2012, 2013),
                     "Count" = c(0, 1, 5, 0, 3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0,
                                 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 8, 11, 7, 2, 3,
                                 1, 1, 0, 2, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3,
                                 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2,
                                 3, 1, 1, 5, 0, 1, 2, 8, 11, 7, 2, 3, 1, 1,
                                 0, 2, 5, 1, 1, 3, 0),
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Summary data frame with species layer below.

```
new.frame.2 <- data.frame(
                 "Line.ID" = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                 "Species" = c(rep("T. rex", 2), rep("T. bataar", 3)),
                 "Site" = c("Big Red", "Supermax", "Big Red", "Supermax", "Oz"),
                 "Total.years" = c(9, 10, 5, 4, 2),
                 "Years.3" = c(4, 5, 3, 1, 1),
                 "Years.4" = c(2, 3, 2, 1, 0),
                 "Years.5" = c(2, 1, 2, 0, 0),
                 "Total.pos" = c(8, 8, 5, 4, 1),
                 "Pos.3" = c(3, 5, 3, 1, 1),
                 "Pos.4" = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 0),
                 "Pos.5" = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem? This sounds quite feasible, but it also sounds like you're trying to get people to do your work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `table` to count the frequency and do this in single `group_by`.

```
library(dplyr)

example.frame %>%
   group_by(Site) %>%
   summarise(Total_Years = n_distinct(Year), 
             Years.3 = sum(table(Year) >= 3), 
             Years.4 = sum(table(Year) >= 4), 
             Years.5 = sum(table(Year) >= 5), 
             Total.Pos = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) > 0),
             Pos.3 = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) >= 3),
             Pos.4 = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) >= 4),
             Pos.5 = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) >= 5)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   mutate(Line.ID = row_number()) %>%
  select(Line.ID, everything())

#  Line.ID Site     Total_Years Years.3 Years.4 Years.5 Total.Pos Pos.3 Pos.4 Pos.5
#    <int> <chr>          <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1       1 Big Red            9       4       2       2         8     3     1     1
#2       2 Supermax          10       5       3       1         8     5     2     0
```

For second question, we just need to add an additional `group_by` variable `Species` and it should work.

```
example.frame.2 %>%
   group_by(Species, Site) %>%
   summarise(Total_Years = n_distinct(Year), 
             Years.3 = sum(table(Year) >= 3), 
             Years.4 = sum(table(Year) >= 4), 
             Years.5 = sum(table(Year) >= 5), 
             Total.Pos = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) > 0),
             Pos.3 = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) >= 3),
             Pos.4 = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) >= 4),
             Pos.5 = sum(table(Year[Count > 0]) >= 5)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Line.ID = row_number()) %>%
    select(Line.ID, everything())


# Line.ID Species   Site     Total_Years Years.3 Years.4 Years.5 Total.pos Pos.3 Pos.4 Pos.5
#    <int> <chr>     <chr>          <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1       1 T. bataar Big Red            5       3       2       2         5     3     1     1
#2       2 T. bataar Oz                 2       1       0       0         1     1     0     0
#3       3 T. bataar Supermax           4       1       1       0         4     1     1     0
#4       4 T. rex    Big Red            9       4       2       2         8     3     1     1
#5       5 T. rex    Supermax          10       5       3       1         8     5     2     0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this programatically (assuming that we need to do this for multiple comparisons)

```
library(data.table)
# set an identifier for values to compare
n1 <- 3:5
# convert the data.frame to data.table, get the Total_Years, Total_pos
# grouped by Site
dt1 <- setDT(example.frame)[, .(Total_Years = uniqueN(Year),
           Total_pos = sum(tabulate(Year[Count > 0]) > 0)), Site]

# grouped by Site, loop through the Year, 
# Year where 'Count' is greater than 0 with lapply
# get the frequency count with tabulate
# check whether it is greater than or equal to values in n1
# get the sum of logical vector inside Map
# melt into long format 
# dcast the data into wide after doing some transformation
# join with the dt1 on Site
dcast(melt(setnames(example.frame[, lapply(list(Year, Year[Count > 0]),
    function(u) Map(function(x, y) sum(x >= y), list(tabulate(u)), n1)), 
      by = Site], 2:3, c("Year", "Pos")), id.var = "Site")[, 
     variable := paste0(variable, ".", n1)], Site ~ variable)[dt1, on = .(Site)]
#       Site Pos.3 Pos.4 Pos.5 Year.3 Year.4 Year.5 Total_Years Total_pos
#1:  Big Red     3     1     1      4      2      2           9         8
#2: Supermax     5     2     0      5      3      1          10         8
```

---

For the second dataset, add the 'Species' also in the grouping variable and do the same as before

```
dt1 <- setDT(example.frame.2)[, .(Total_Years = uniqueN(Year),
       Total_pos = sum(tabulate(Year[Count > 0]) > 0)), .(Species, Site)]

dcast(melt(setnames(example.frame.2[, lapply(list(Year, Year[Count > 0]), 
 function(u) Map(function(x, y) sum(x >= y), list(tabulate(u)), n1)),
   by = .(Species, Site)], 3:4, c("Year", "Pos")),
   id.var = c("Species", "Site"))[, variable := paste0(variable, ".", n1)], 
     Species + Site ~ variable)[dt1, on = .(Species, Site)]
#     Species     Site Pos.3 Pos.4 Pos.5 Year.3 Year.4 Year.5 Total_Years Total_pos
#1:    T. rex  Big Red     3     1     1      4      2      2           9         8
#2:    T. rex Supermax     5     2     0      5      3      1          10         8
#3: T. bataar  Big Red     3     1     1      3      2      2           5         5
#4: T. bataar Supermax     1     1     0      1      1      0           4         4
#5: T. bataar       Oz     1     0     0      1      0      0           2         1
```

---

Also, this can be done with `tidyverse`.  It is better to construct a function for repeated use

```
library(tidyverse)
countFn <- function(data, grpVars, yearCol, countCol, n) {
          yearCol <- enquo(yearCol)
          countCol <- enquo(countCol)

          yearnm <- paste0("Years.", n)
          posnm <- paste0("Pos.", n)

     d1 <- data %>%
             group_by_at(grpVars) %>%
             summarise(Total_Years = n_distinct(!! yearCol),
                 Total_pos = sum(tabulate((!! yearCol)[(!! countCol)> 0]) > 0))

     data %>% 
         group_by_at(grpVars) %>%
         summarise(Col = list(map(list((!! yearCol), (!! yearCol)[(!!countCol) > 0] ),
                  ~ map2_dfc(list(tabulate(.x)), n, 
                            ~ sum(.x >= .y) ) 







              ) %>% map2_dfc(., list(yearnm, posnm), set_names)


              )) %>%          
                   right_join(d1) %>%
                   unnest(Col)



}
```

-testing

```
n1 <- 3:5
countFn(example.frame, "Site", Year, Count, n1)
# A tibble: 2 x 9
#  Site     Total_Years Total_pos Years.3 Years.4 Years.5 Pos.3 Pos.4 Pos.5
#  <chr>          <int>     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 Big Red            9         8       4       2       2     3     1     1
#2 Supermax          10         8       5       3       1     5     2     0

countFn(example.frame.2, c("Species", "Site"), Year, Count, n1)
# A tibble: 5 x 10
# Groups:   Species [2]
#  Species   Site     Total_Years Total_pos Years.3 Years.4 Years.5 Pos.3 Pos.4 Pos.5
#  <chr>     <chr>          <int>     <int>   <int>   <int>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 T. bataar Big Red            5         5       3       2       2     3     1     1
#2 T. bataar Oz                 2         1       1       0       0     1     0     0
#3 T. bataar Supermax           4         4       1       1       0     1     1     0
#4 T. rex    Big Red            9         8       4       2       2     3     1     1
#5 T. rex    Supermax          10         8       5       3       1     5     2     0
```